# Adding rolled-in seasonings to pita bread

Tags: middle-eastern-cuisine, pita

Usually when I make flatbread, I roll-in seasonings (ie: minced garlic and celery) before cooking. There doesn't seem to be a problem with the dough being too wet or doughy if I only use about a teaspoon of seasoning per ball, and only roll the seasoning into the dough once or twice.

The rolled-in seasonings are my favorite part about flatbread- I prefer the thickness and fluffiness of pita much more. I tried combining the two by using my favorite pita recipe and rolling in seasonings before cooking. This completely changed the texture of my pita, and ended up a doughy mess (ie: it was slimy while cooking and tasted too wet after coming off the skillet- pockets did not form at all).

Has anyone tried this with different results, or found a way to successfully add seasonings into pita dough with real pita bread results? Or is it a lost cause? I'm wondering why it continually works with flatbread dough but not with pita.

Comment: Did you add anything containing salt before the first prove?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I created the wheat sponge and let that sit overnight. (Not sure if that counts as the first proof or not.) Then I added salt, olive oil, more flour - knead - proof it for a few hours - then it's ready to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that flatbreads are a single layer whereas pita and similar pan breads (there is an Indian version as well [paratha]) develop a pocket in between the layers (usually due to trapped steam).

For pan breads, I've noticed the amount of heat is very important.  Too much and it burns and too little and you don't get the pocket/lift.

In this case, the added wet ingredients might be preventing the steam from building up and forming a pocket.  Either by absorbing the pan heat in the area or stitching the top and bottom by sticking to both sides.

You might be able to add the extra ingredients after you've flattened the dough ball and still get a pocket (carefully making sure there is layer of clean dough between top and bottom).  Or go for reverse, take a look at this [vegetable stuffed panbread](http://jyotsna-pant.blogspot.ca/2012/12/parantha-sadabaharvegetables-stuffed.html) which does not have any pockets but looks yummy none-the-less.

Otherwise, if you keep baking the wetness out, you might end up with a workable focaccia.  In general, adding wet ingredients to baked breads throws the formula out of balance.

Comment: I just finished that parantha recipe and it came out so good! Very similar to the pita bread I make except with tons more flavor. I used lentils, chiles, and roasted garlic as the filling.

Comment: @mdeggs nicely done. Buon apetito!